# Import SQL data into MySQL database for wordpress login

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, wordpress

I own a SQL database that contains about 6000+ user login and that supports a web application. I want to use the same login for a wordpress website for the same client. Is there a way where I can import login data from SQL into MySQL wp_users table? Or any other alternatives exist to achieve this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: If the hashing system is the same, then yes, you can probably export data from one DB and then import it into another DB. A simple your written script will do that.

Comment: @jarlh SQL database is being used for a web applicattion. It has all the 6000 login. MySQL database has only one login i.e. the admin login, I need those 6000 login login credentials to be in MySQL as well.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean _SQL Server database_? SQL is a language.

Comment: Yep, the SQL server running on IIS

Answer (score 0):

you can create table "user" and match its fields with WordPress table then check WordPress user table data types. Then match both table configurations after that export that table and import on WordPress database.

Comment: Any tutorial that supports your answer? It seems promising but the steps were not precise.

Comment: you can provide me structure of user table